# Merging of two maps having different data in ecognition

Tags: ecognition, image-segmentation

I would like to synchronise two maps having two data (map1 for building and map2 for

vegetation) into main map.I used the rule set of "working with maps".But it doesn't merges the

data.I am using eCognition 8.7 version.My task is to classify building in one map and

vegetation in another map of the same area.After classification I want to synchronise the

extracted building and vegetation into the main map.I could do up to this level , but it comes

as two levels in main map.I have to get it in a single level in main map.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange, it would be very helpful if you could edit your question and include a few more details about your specific situation.  You should especially make sure to include some info about what software you are using (ex: "We're trying to do this in ArcGIS Desktop v10.2 with an Advanced level license"). That will likely help people better understand your question and give you better answers.

Comment: Have you looked on the ecognition support pages (https://trimble.zendesk.com/hc/en-us)?

Comment: Do you have actual *maps*? Do you know the spatial reference systems involved? Or do you have *images*? How were the images captured?